# Can't connect to remote mysql with PHP

Tags: mysql, database, connection

I have a database running on a server which my desktop program updates. My program is written in C# and I can connect just fine using the Mysql Connector.

```
private void Initialize()
    {
        server = "xxx.com";
        database = "test01";
        uid = "user";
        password = "pass";
        string connectionString;
        connectionString = "SERVER=" + server + ";" + "DATABASE=" +
        database + ";" + "UID=" + uid + ";" + "PASSWORD=" + password + ";";

        connection = new MySqlConnection(connectionString);
    }
```

I want to be able to retrieve some data from my database with a PHP script on my website, but I can't get even a simple connection to work with my database, with the same connection information. I am not very familiar with php, and I'm hoping that I'm just making a stupid mistake :)

```
$con = mysql_connect("xxx.com","user","pass");
if (!$con)
{
  die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
}
```

This just keeps dying... Could someone tell me that I am doing something stupid and tell me how to fix it?

Thanks in advance,
LordJesus

**EDIT:**
The error I keep getting is this:
Could not connect: Lost connection to MySQL server at 'reading initial communication packet', system error: 110

**EDIT #2:**
My 'user' already has been granted access on '%' which should cover all IP's. When I run phpinfo(); I get a lot of info including a section called mysql with info there.

**SOLVED... OR UNRESOLVED?**
OK, I think I know why it fails. My website is hosted at one.com, and chatting with one of their supporters I learned that they do not allow connections to remote databases, only the one on my domain. Which is not what I want. So I didn't solve it, but I found out why I got that error. Now I need to find a way to work around that...

Comment: Any specific error messages? Are you connecting to the right port?

Comment: What exactly happens? You should get some errors.

Comment: Is your php configure properly.. Try first to print phpinfo(); then check if you can see the MySql information. If no results for MySql you need to configure it first. Check this http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysql.installation.php

Comment: When runnning the phpinfo(); I get a section called 'mysql' which has a bunch of info in it. So I'm guessing MySql is configured? It should be, as the site is running a Joomla website.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds to me like your environment is as follows:  Your desktop with a C# program, your MySQL server located on another machine and finally and web server that is autonomous and not attached to either of those systems.  If this is the case, you need to grant permissions to your database from the web server.

The following will grant select permission to your webserver.

```
GRANT SELECT ON test01.* TO 'user'@'ip.of.the.webserver' IDENTIFIED BY 'pass';
```

Comment: If your web server has a valid reverse lookup, MySQL may use that for authentication purposes.  You may have to take a look at the reverse DNS of your web server and use that in place of the IP address for the GRANT statement.

Comment: I just tried doing this, but it didn't solve it... @Sean C. How do I get the reverse DNS of my web server?

Comment: If you have access to dig, you can try to use that tool.  Here is an example.  If I dig www.google.ca I get five IPs.  One is, 74.125.226.146; so I'll use that as an example.  Reverse lookups are handled by pointer records (PTR). `dig PTR 146.226.125.74.in-addr.arpa` will attempt to find an associated PTR record for the address.

Comment: Actually, there is a switch you can apply to dig to accomplish the same thing.  `dig -x 74.125.226.146`

Comment: The thing is, I have already granted access on '%' for my user. That should cover all IP's and reverse IP's, shouldn't it?

Comment: If you granted for user@'%' then yes, you have proper access.  What is output from the `die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());` statment?

Comment: @Sean C. The output from the error statement is: Could not connect: Lost connection to MySQL server at 'reading initial communication packet', system error: 110

Comment: Check my.cnf for the bind-address of your database server.  It sounds like the connection is being closed.